# Allow switching apps in iOS a without losing edit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

This is a feature request for the iOS app.

Today I was writing a complicated answer (or maybe it was a long comment - I forget) using the app. I wanted to check a fact so toggled to the browser. When I came back to the app, instead of returning where I left off I was returned to the front page - and my edits appeared to be lost...

This is obviously massively inconvenient - there are other ways of achieving the goal of toggling (using the mobile site instead of the app) but that defeats the purpose of having an app.

It's a bit late to be asking Santa. But I _ have_ been good this year...

Comment: By the way, if it was indeed an answer, it was more than likely saved as a draft. If you go back to that question and try to answering it, the app will reload it whatever you had typed. However, that's besides what you are asking for, which is restoring the app to its previous state.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky - that's interesting, and I will experiment with that; but you are right that it doesn't address my main feature request, since when toggling doesn't get me back to the edit I was working on, I may not even be able to _find_ the question again - on some sites the front page cycles quite rapidly...

Comment: This is in progress but a huge undertaking.  The basic problem is that iOS is killing the app in the background and we're taking you back to the feed on restart.  I'm tackling the problem from the perspective of state restoration (reconstructing what you were looking at when the app quit) and Arie is working on improvements to the drafting experience.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort on this - it will make life better. And the use case is very common... At least for me (invariably I want to add references etc to my answers, and that requires toggling).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So... this turned into a 7 week project... but it's [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)!  The app now uses the [iOS State Preservation and Restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW2) APIs to reconstruct the view controller hierarchy if the app was terminated in the background.

Arie also did some visual improvements for drafting as part of another feature request so you can move between the draft and the parent question without losing context.

Both are in the beta channel now but I'm planning a feature freeze so we can get the app to the store in a few weeks.

Comment: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thank you very much and I look forward to seeing the app

Comment: The "switch between draft and question" feature is one I am also eagerly anticipating. It's good to see our suggestions being acted upon!